# Adobe AIR doesn't save file with file's extension

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe

I am working on Adobe AIR application and some test users report to me about same issue. When they try to save the project file from this application, they have no possibility to add any extension (".txt", ".xml" or any other) to the file. All these users use Microsoft Windows.

What can be the cause of the problem?

Comment: How are you saving the file?  Show some code, or at least reference the classes and methods you're using.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is a pretty standard issue with the browseForSave method of saving files. This post should give you a workable solution for ensuring the correct filetype is entered: http://analogd.com/blog/adobe-air/adobe-air-tips-serie-browseforsave-set-default-file-extension-and-validatemodify/